# Adding Pharmacode to PyZbar

Tags: barcode

I have an inspection application in pharma. I need to inspect batch numbers and Pharmacodes on labels using OpenCV. I thought of using PyZbar but it doesn't support Pharmacode. How can I add more codes, like Pharmacode, to PyZbar?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pharmacode (also known as code32) is implemented as code39 using a radix-32 "compression scheme".  So you can use PyZbar, with the understanding that you will get a code39 decode from the library and then have to convert the value from base-32 to base-10.

Note that there is no way of knowing whether a code39 "read" is actually code32 or just plain code39.

This is some javascript that converts a code39 value to its original code32 string:

```
// code32 radix set (missing the vowels AEIO)
const code32set = '0123456789BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
function code39toCode32(val) {
    if (/[^0-9BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ]/.test(val)) {
        throw new Error("Not code32");
    }
    let res = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        res = res * 32 + code32set.indexOf(val[i]);
    }
    let code32 = '' + res;
    if (code32.length < 9) {
        code32 = ('000000000' + code32).slice(-9);
    }
    return code32;
}
```

That function should translate to python pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, Code32 is the Italian pharma code, and it is a special type and differs for the general Pharmacode. Is it possible to add new codes to Zbar?

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bad case of necro-posting but I've been aksing myselfe the same question.

I couldn't figure out how to add a code type to an existing library, but ended up writing my own Pharmacode reader using only OpenCv and python. Once you know where the code is in the picture, it's realy not too hard to decode it, since all you need is the width of the elements in a list, then you can just set a threshhold and go over your list with

```
for i in range(list):
    if i < thresh:
        code.append(pow(2,i))
    if i >= thresh:
        code.append(pow(2,i+1))
code = sum(code)
```